# Iterating through objects in underscore.js templates

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Help! This should't be so difficult, so I assume I'm missing something easy...

I have a variable that's serving as an underscore template. Here's an example (there's more to it, but for simplicity's sake, this is the code that matters):

```
var template = '<% _.each(favorites, function(value, key) { %> <li><%= key %>: <%= value %></li> <% }); %>';
```

And what's in 'favorites' you might ask? It's coming from a JSON object that looks something like this (cutting out the other JSON).

```
"favorites" : [
    { "food" : "shrimp" },
    { "drink" : "none" }
]
```

Why on earth can I not figure out how to get the key/value pairs to output in the template. All I want to do is print something like this:

```
<li>food: shrimp</li>
<li>drink: none</li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you have is a collection not an object. You have to loop the **array** and access the keys with dot notation. But your data structure isn't quite right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with a different data structure, a proper collection:

```
favorites: [
  {type: "food", name: "shrimp"},
  {type: "drink" name: "none"}
];
```

Then you can create your template like:

```
var template = [
  '<% _.each(favorites, function(item) { %>',
    '<li><%= item.type %>: <%= item.name %></li>',
  '<% }); %>'
].join('');
```

Comment: That totally works. Thank you, thank you, thank you!